# Como esconder un Option específico de un Select usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un Select que muestra una serie de options, cuando el usuario clicka en uno se añade a un div que tengo más abajo, hasta ahí todo bién. Luego me plateé quitar el option que el usuario clicke pero si más tarde quiero que se vuelva a añadir al Select si lo elimino del div *(esto todavía no lo tengo programado, y no es lo que pido)* no me sirve. Por tanto la opción más válida para mí es que el **Option que clicke se haga invisible en el Select** .Si seleccionas un item que no sea un grupo está puesto que se borra pero yo no quiero eso quiero que se haga invisible.

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

**Lo que tengo actualmente**:

```js
  function myFunction() {
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var child = document.getElementById("mySelect").children;
    var segments = ['grupo1', 'grupo2', 'grupo3'];
    var grupo1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    var grupo2 = ['e','f', 'g', 'h'];
    var grupo3 = ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'];
    document.getElementById("etiquetas-seleccionadas").append(x + ' | ');
    console.dir(x);
    console.dir(child);
    console.dir("--------------------------------");
    // borrar del select el item seleccionado
    for (let item of child) {
      if(item.value == x) {
        console.dir("Encontrado --> " + item.value);
        //borrar aquellos items que pertenecen a un segmento
        console.dir("Array Segments:");
        console.dir(segments.indexOf(item.value));
        if (segments.indexOf(item.value) >= 0) {
          console.dir("Es un segmento: " + item.value);
          if(segments.indexOf(item.value) == 0) {
            console.dir("Es el segmento grupo1: " + item.value);
              for(let item2 of child) {
                if(grupo1.indexOf(item2.value) >= 0) {
                  console.dir("Se borran todos los que pertenecen a grupo1");
                  console.dir("Son: " + item2.value);
                  //$item2.prop('disabled', true);
                }
              }
          }else if(segments.indexOf(item.value) ==1) {
            console.dir("Es el segmento grupo2: " + item.value);
              for(let item2 of child) {
                if(grupo2.indexOf(item2.value) >= 0) {
                  console.dir("Se borran todos los que pertenecen a grupo2");
                  console.dir("Son: " + item2.value);
                  // select.remove(item2.index);
                }
              }
          }else {
            console.dir("Es el segmento grupo3: " + item.value);
              for(let item2 of child) {
                if(grupo3.indexOf(item2.value) >= 0) {
                  console.dir("Se borran todos los que pertenecen a grupo3");
                  console.dir("Son: " + item2.value);
                  // select.remove(item2.index);
                }
              }
          }
        }else {
          console.dir("Es una item: " + item.value)
          select.remove(item.index);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
.sticker{
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #d6d9dc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(59,64,69,0.1);
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#stickerTitle{
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #595151;
  color:#ffffff;
}
#stickerTitle h1{
  text-align: center;
}
#stickerTitle a{
  padding-top: 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline;
  color:#ffffff;
  float:right;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sticker">
      <div id="stickerTitle">
        <h1>Supscriptions</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="etiquetas-seleccionadas">
        <p>Etiquetas seleccionadas</p>
      </div>
      <form class="fsticker" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method ="post">
        <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="">-----------</option>
          <option value="grupo1">Grupo1</option>
          <option value="grupo2">Grupo2</option>
          <option value="grupo3">Grupo3</option>
          <option value="">-----------</option>
          <option value="a">A</option>
          <option value="b">B</option>
          <option value="c">C</option>
          <option value="d">D</option>
          <option value="e">E</option>
          <option value="f">F</option>
          <option value="g">G</option>
          <option value="h">H</option>
          <option value="i">I</option>
          <option value="j">J</option>
          <option value="k">K</option>
          <option value="l">L</option>
        </select>
        <button id="Bsticker" type= submit >Modify</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

PD: el botón de Modify no hace nada, todavía :D.

Gracias de por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sustituyendo la línea `select.remove(item.index);` por `select.options[select.selectedIndex].style.display = "none";` conseguirías ponerle la propiedad `display: none` al `<option>` seleccionado.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var child = document.getElementById("mySelect").children;
    var segments = ['grupo1', 'grupo2', 'grupo3'];
    var grupo1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    var grupo2 = ['e','f', 'g', 'h'];
    var grupo3 = ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'];
    document.getElementById("etiquetas-seleccionadas").append(x + ' | ');
    //console.dir(x);
    //console.dir(child);
    //console.dir("--------------------------------");
    // borrar del select el item seleccionado
    for (let item of child) {
      if(item.value == x) {
        //console.dir("Encontrado --> " + item.value);
        //borrar aquellos items que pertenecen a un segmento
        //console.dir("Array Segments:");
        //console.dir(segments.indexOf(item.value));
        if (segments.indexOf(item.value) >= 0) {
          //console.dir("Es un segmento: " + item.value);
          if(segments.indexOf(item.value) == 0) {
            //console.dir("Es el segmento grupo1: " + item.value);
              for(let item2 of child) {
                if(grupo1.indexOf(item2.value) >= 0) {
                  //console.dir("Se borran todos los que pertenecen a grupo1");
                  //console.dir("Son: " + item2.value);
                  //$item2.prop('disabled', true);
                }
              }
          }else if(segments.indexOf(item.value) ==1) {
            //console.dir("Es el segmento grupo2: " + item.value);
              for(let item2 of child) {
                if(grupo2.indexOf(item2.value) >= 0) {
                  //console.dir("Se borran todos los que pertenecen a grupo2");
                  //console.dir("Son: " + item2.value);
                  // select.remove(item2.index);
                }
              }
          }else {
            console.dir("Es el segmento grupo3: " + item.value);
              for(let item2 of child) {
                if(grupo3.indexOf(item2.value) >= 0) {
                  //console.dir("Se borran todos los que pertenecen a grupo3");
                  //console.dir("Son: " + item2.value);
                  // select.remove(item2.index);
                }
              }
          }
        }else {
          //console.dir("Es una item: " + item.value)
          select.options[select.selectedIndex].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
.sticker{
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #d6d9dc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(59,64,69,0.1);
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#stickerTitle{
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #595151;
  color:#ffffff;
}
#stickerTitle h1{
  text-align: center;
}
#stickerTitle a{
  padding-top: 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline;
  color:#ffffff;
  float:right;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sticker">
      <div id="stickerTitle">
        <h1>Supscriptions</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="etiquetas-seleccionadas">
        <p>Etiquetas seleccionadas</p>
      </div>
      <form class="fsticker" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method ="post">
        <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="">-----------</option>
          <option value="grupo1">Grupo1</option>
          <option value="grupo2">Grupo2</option>
          <option value="grupo3">Grupo3</option>
          <option value="">-----------</option>
          <option value="a">A</option>
          <option value="b">B</option>
          <option value="c">C</option>
          <option value="d">D</option>
          <option value="e">E</option>
          <option value="f">F</option>
          <option value="g">G</option>
          <option value="h">H</option>
          <option value="i">I</option>
          <option value="j">J</option>
          <option value="k">K</option>
          <option value="l">L</option>
        </select>
        <button id="Bsticker" type= submit >Modify</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba :D